# Unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF)?

Tags: php, wordpress

I’m having trouble with WordPress tags. After creating a Tag and attaching the tag to a post the URL give me the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) in /var/www/html/example.com/wp-content/themes/example/index.php on line 30

And here is the code for my index.php:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Blog Page
*/
get_header(); 
?>
        <!-- PAGE LAYOUT //-->
        <section id="page-title" style="background: url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/blog-title-bg.jpg'; ?>) no-repeat center top / cover;">
            <div class="page-wrapper">
                <h1>Our Blog</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div id="page" class="interior"<?php if(get_field('content_background')) : ?> style="background: url(<?php echo get_field('content_background'); ?>) no-repeat center top / 100% auto;"<? endif; ?>>
            <div class="page-wrapper">
                <main>
                    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="blog-post">
                            <h3 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                            <div class="meta">Posted: <?php echo get_the_time('F j, Y'); ?> | By: <?php the_author(); ?></div>
                            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                            <p align="right"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">&raquo; Read More</a></p>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </main>
            </div>
            <?php get_sidebar('testimonials'); ?>
        </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Please any guidance will be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Likely the issue is `<? endif; ?>`. That requires short tags to be enabled. Change to `<?php ...`